# Develop 1 Facebook Contact Importer (After Authorization of User -> Display names & emails of their friends)

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to grab the contact lists (frnd name & frnd email) of the user after authorization on facebook.

What to do?

I had created 1 apps on developer, facebook, which api i had to use regarding it graph or facebook connect, or what to do?

We have 1 social networking in php in smarty framework.!

Answer (score 1):

Friend's e-mails are not available in the API. Take a look in the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/) and you'll see that it says "N/A" for friends email (at the very bottom om the table).

Comment: It's not possible to fetch friend's emails via the Facebook API, simple as that.